# Why blazor app doesn't work when i change root to folder "_framework"

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I change my base href in `index.html`: was `href="/"` has become `href="/schedule/"`

Also i change `Configure`:

```
 app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),@"Schedule.Client", @"dist")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/schedule")
            });
```

Here located my files

[image: Here located my files:]

css, js, resources work good, but _framework which includes wasm files and doesn't work correct.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Schedule</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="css/Resources/icon_title.png" />
    <base href="/schedule/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/btnstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/SetScroll.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <app>
        <div id="demo" style="margin:auto; top:30px;">
            <img src="css/Resources/logo-fin.png" />
            <div class="circle fas fa-spinner"></div>
        </div>
    </app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I start my app, I get error
[image]

When i use `href="/"`, all is correct

What could be wrong?
Thanks!

Update

I have found the same problem and solution, but there is used a Azure CLI:
https://anthonychu.ca/post/blazor-azure-storage-static-websites/

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked this question on github and get a answer. You should use a method to set a correct root: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1421

```
app.Map("/schedule", subdirApp =>
{
    subdirApp.UseBlazor<Startup>();
});
```

I wrote this code in `Server.Startup`.
In UseBlazor i have written `Client.Startup`.